# QGIS: Creating duplicate database merges all points, geometry remains separate but trying to select one selects all

Tags: qgis, sql-server

The duplicate database was created using various methods (to debug this issue), FME writing a new database based on the old database as input, MSSQL Management Studio, SQL, as well as putting the shapefiles in an empty DB.

For most of these all points merge, but when I duplicated from `Management studio` only some points merged for reasons that elude me.

Any ideas on a reason this might happen? Im fairly new to QGIS (worked mostly with ArcMAP) so if there is a setting I might miss I probably have. Alternatively, is there a reason points merge when you duplicate databases? Any good tools to "ungroup" points?